# User profile invalid error in merge profile form

Tags: support, profile-page, login, help-center

I created a new profile to get access to Stack Overflow in Portuguese, with this profile I have, I couldn't don't know why. But now I am deactivating the email box I use to log in, and I it seams the email can't be changed. I log in this profile by Yahoo, and the other one by Exchange. How am I trying:

I log in my newer profile by Exchange and get the user profile link, than log off and log in back to my older profile using Yahoo. Than I access Help Center contact->submit chasing "I need to merge user profiles". The field "Your profile" is filled, the "Your other profile link" I just paste the link I got:

```
https://stackexchange.com/users/4156575/user6492
```

The form is not sent and the error message is shown: "oops! this isn't a link to a valid profile"

But this profile is very valid, I am using... now what?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I believe the profile link always needs to be an *user* profile, not an *account* profile. So if you request the merge on pt.stackoverflow.com, I believe you need to provide this url: `https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/6492/user6492` and if your request the merge here on meta you need to provide `https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/329895/user6492` but I think it is wise to wait a bit for confirmation.

Comment: Checked in [chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6268926#6268926) and my assumptions are correct.

Comment: Great! The form were submitted  - will wait for an answer. I suggest you @rene to answer this question so I can mark as solved. Even if my request is denied for some reason, this step is ok. When accessing stackoverflow in portuguese, there is no pt in the url, I copied directly from browser url request, probably because were logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am copying the comment of rene to leave this question with a proper answer.

The profile link always needs to be an user profile, not an account profile. So if you request the merge on pt.stackoverflow.com, you need to provide this url:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/6492/user6492

and if your request the merge here on meta you need to provide

https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/329895/user6492

In my case, I used the pt url and it worked!

Comment: This answer has my approval  ...

Comment: adding "meta"  in the url still gives me the completely useless response of "oops! this isn't a link to a valid profile", that sucks, isn't it?